# What is the use of collection mappings and association mappings?

Tags: hibernate, collections, hibernate-mapping

I am working On `Hibernate` With `Spring`

If  first  i  created  database  and  i  used Hibernate DAOs layer along with  DAOsImpl.

and i  simply  mapped my model classes  to database tables with simple mapping.then  what is the use of  Collection Mapping,Association Mapping????

without collection mapping  and  association mapping  i can do  my work whatever i  want.

please give  me  any   good  explanation.

Comment: Collection mapping is used to define relations between entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are mapping your model classes you are mapping the entities to the database, specifying types of fields, primary keys ...

But when you are using Collection mapping you are defining the way these entities are related to each others, you are simply mapping the relationships/[associations](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) between entities. (specifying foreign keys, join tables, ...).

Take a look at the **[Collection mapping Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html)** for further information.

For example for the given association:

[image]

You need Collection mapping to specify the type of relation between an `author` and a `book`.

Comment: if  i  don't  specify relationship between entities because first i  created database and in database  i  have specify all foreign key and primary key all things  i  created  first then  what is the use of  Collection mapping ????

Comment: because first i created that  database and i am not  defining relationship between entities...

Comment: it means that  i  have two ways to define relationship between entities either i can  define in  Hibernate Model classes or i can define in database...


if i  define relationship among  tables  at the time of creating database then  i am getting full advantage of  Hibernate or  what ??????

Comment: If  i  define relationship among tables at the time of database creation and now i am  using  Hibernate then i am  getting full advantage of Hibernate ????????  

or should i define relationship among entities at the time of writing model classes instead of creating database first which one is better ?????

Comment: ,please leave your answer it will be very helpful  for me ...  :)  thankx

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment and adjust your question with the information from the comments.

Comment: Yes this is the way hibernate manages relations, and why would you fix this in the db if you can do it automatically with hibernate.

Comment: i am integrating this application with Spring ... so what is the best way to use Hibernate with  DAO along with DAOsImpl ?  or  anything else ????

Comment: You will just need to specify the name of the database in the configuration file and hibernate will manage everything for you.