# What is the benefit to use of Association Mapping in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

In Hibernate We can establish relationship among Entities by Association

But what is the benefit to establish relationship among entities..

Can anybody give me good example ????

Thank you In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more a **design** or a **database** question rather than a `hibernate` one, but let's answer it in a more generic way:

In every `project` or `system` there are objects or entities that make this system work. But these objects are entended to communicate and interact with each others and with the system, so the question is *how to design these interactions*?

**Relationships mapping** is the answer to this question: in any System relationships are used to specify the **interactions** between the system objects or components and the **type** of interaction between them, let's take a look at the same association example of the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747335/3669624):

[image]

You need Collection mapping to specify the **type** of relation between an `author` and a `book`, in fact this relationship(association) states that a book is written by one or many Professors or Authors, and an author can write many books.

*Without relationship mapping we are not able to describe these statements for the system or the application.*